# Drupal commerce add product to pending order

Tags: drupal, drupal-commerce

I have already paid order in commerce (has status pending for example), but i need to add one more product to that order and pay for newly added product. Is there way to do that? If no, how can I solve this other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you have passed the 'check out' page and paid for the products, no matter in what status the order is, you can not alter from admin side -- without hacking it!